# how to restrict the standard users to delete the records, only system admin should have permission to delete records

Tags: permissions, delete, record

What are the steps to set permissions that system admin should only be able to delete records i.e. we have to restrict the standard users to delete the records.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it on profile level.
Read this article:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_object_perms.htm&type=0

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign `DELETE` permission of that particular object for standard user's profile.

Refer [Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_userprofiles.htm&type=0)